# How to avoid showing all elements at once under search bar in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I tried this and all the products appear under the search bar even before inputting value to search for, how to show products only when searched for. please help Thanks in advance

**Searchbar.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {storeProducts} from '../data';
import Product from './Product';
import styled from 'styled-components';

export default class SearchBar extends Component {
 constructor(){
  super();
  this.state={
   search: '',
  

  };
 }
 updateSearch(event) {
 this.setState({search:event.target.value.substr(0,20)})
 }
 render() {
  let filteredProducts = storeProducts.filter(
   (product) => {
    return product.title.indexOf(this.state.search) !== -1;
   }
  );
  return (
   <SearchWrapper>
   <input type="text" value={this.state.search} onChange={this.updateSearch.bind(this)} placeholder="search"/>
   {filteredProducts.map((product) => {
    return <li> <Product product={product} key={product.title}/></li>
   })}
   </SearchWrapper>
  )
 }
}
const SearchWrapper = styled.div`
background:#f6f6f6;
padding: 30px 200px;
input{
 border:1px solid #76bd05;
 width:40rem;
}
li{
 height 50px;
 list-style:none;
}`;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because `this.state.search` is initially an empty string `''`. When you filter your products you are using `indexOf(this.state.search)`, which will return true for every single product, since empty string will match anything.

I would simply add a condition in your render function. If `this.state.search.length > 0` then show the filtered products.

```js
{this.state.search.length > 0 && filteredProducts.map((product) => {
  return (
    <li>
      <Product product={product} key={product.title} />
    </li>
  );
})}
```